# Helm Uninstall to Remove Release if exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am using Helm 3 and I have 3 different values.yaml per environments. If my initial release ends up in a failed state to avoid error while running `helm upgrade --install myapp-dev` I would like to remove release if exists for related environment.

So according to the below script, if deploy stage runs successfully , then it will uninstall the release for next stage. What is the best practices to do this according to the in case of failure for previous stage?Should I use try/catch block or post section? Meanwhile, in which condition should I use this clean up really?

```
        stage('Deploy to staging'){
          when{
            beforeAgent true
            expression{return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/test"}
        }
        steps{
            script{
                def namespace = "test"
                def ENV = "test"
                sh " helm upgrade myapp-test my-chart --install -f values.${ENV}.yaml --namespace ${namespace}"          
            }
        }
    }

    stage('Cleanup Stage'){
      when{
        beforeAgent true
        expression{return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/test"}
    }
        steps{
            script{
                //Uninstall a release from the cluster
                sh "helm uninstall myapp-test"

                //See currently deployed releases
                sh "helm list -all"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkinsfile you should actually do all the cleanup in the `post` section, which can executed no matter what wrong happened. For example, in your case:

```
stages {
        stage('Deploy to staging'){
          when{
            beforeAgent true
            expression{return env.GIT_BRANCH == "origin/test"}
          }
          steps{
            script{
                def namespace = "test"
                def ENV = "test"
                sh " helm upgrade myapp-test my-chart --install -f values.${ENV}.yaml -- 
                 namespace ${namespace}"          
            }
          }
      }
}
post { 
  always { 
    helm uninstall myapp-test
  }
}
```

That would guarantee to keep your environment clean no matter of the failures in between.

Comment: Can I use post section for similar stage such as dev and production. I have the same stage for deploy to production and deploy to development environment.

Comment: or Should I run the rest of command such helm uninstall myapp-prod in the same post section

Comment: `post` actually applies to the whole pipeline, not to a separate stage. So if you have stages installing to separate testing environments, you probably want to make the clean-up for all them in the post section. Obviously, for the production, you actually don't want to `uninstall`.

Comment: so the confusion is previous stage make a deployment, then post section will uninstall it again. I mean it will uninstall the release which was install previously. I assume that I need to specifiy some condition